# Problem Retrieving iPhone/iPad store id - Facebook Developer

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, store

I am making an iOS app and using Facebook for developers. However the iPhone and iPad store IDs are unable to be retrieved by Facebook. I know I am using the correct App store IDs so does anybody have an idea what the problem could be?

There are multiple similar question but none of them really answer the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the forum on their support website, the issue seems recurring. 
Attempt the following to resolve:
 i) Switch app from development to live on the facebook developers portal
 ii) Reenter your app id 
iii) Save